# integrate rest-api-sdk-php of paypal to an android app

Tags: android, paypal, sdk

I want to intagrate paypal into my android app, for that, I have integrate the paypal android sdk, but it doesn't fit to all my needs, because I need to custome langage and alert and so on
for that I am wondering if I can integrate the resp api sdk php of paypal into my android app and create my own view in android and communicate directly with my php server which in turn will communicate with paypal server

here is the php rest api [here](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php)

what yould you advise me

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is it that the PayPal Android SDK does not do for you, and/or what language do you need that we do not support?  We have a pretty extensive [set of languages](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/com/paypal/android/sdk/payments/PaymentActivity.html#EXTRA_LANGUAGE_OR_LOCALE) for you to localize with.